# Multithreading in Java findin prime number takes more time?

Tags: java, multithreading, primes

I tried to find out the solution of this problem but was unable to find  it on StackOverflow?

I just want to know that why is my multithreadin working so slow infact it should have done opposite.

```
public class Prime {

    static BufferedWriter writer;
    static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        System.out.println("Without Thread" + findPrime() + " ms");

        System.out.println("With thread : " + findPrimeWithThreads() + " ms");

    }

    public static long findPrimeWithThreads() {

        Instant start = Instant.now();

        int primaryNumber = 3;
        while (primaryNumber <= 100000) {

            int finalPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber;

            new Thread(() -> {
                multiplicationHelper(finalPrimaryNumber);
            }).start();

            new Thread(() -> {
                multiplicationHelper(finalPrimaryNumber+1);
            }).start();

            primaryNumber+=2;
        }

        return Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();

    }

    public static long findPrime() throws IOException {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();

        int primaryNumber = 3;
        while (primaryNumber <= 100000) {

            multiplicationHelper(primaryNumber);

            primaryNumber++;

        }

        return Duration.between(instant, Instant.now()).toMillis();
    }

    public static void multiplicationHelper(int primaryNumber){
        int j = 2;
        boolean isPrime = true;

        while (j <= primaryNumber/2) {
            if (primaryNumber % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (isPrime) {
//            System.out.println("PRIME :: " + primaryNumber);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the code and the output of the code was:

```
Without Thread497 ms
With thread : 22592 ms
```

**Please can you elaborate me why is so and How to increase performance of multithreading?**
I am new to multithreading programming, so am I doing something wrong in this?

Comment: Don't start new threads at every iteration!

Comment: Creating a new thread takes way longer than performing the operation itself. You should create a thread pool and reuse those threads. Or you could create a few threads and assign them parts of the workload.

Comment: New to multithreading in Java? You'll want to get up to speed with this Java Tutorials topic: [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your function to below to

```
public static long findPrimeWithThreads() {

        Instant start = Instant.now();

        int primaryNumber = 3;
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); // considering you've 4 CPU
        while (primaryNumber <= 100000) {
            int finalPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber;
            pool.submit(()->multiplicationHelper(finalPrimaryNumber));
            primaryNumber ++;
        }
        pool.shutdown(); // stop your threads
        return Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();

    }
```

Comment: Submitting 100000 tasks is not very efficient (you're creating 100000 objects). You should just create 4 threads, each one exploring a quarter of the search range.

Comment: Simply showing the OP a code snippet that works better (but in this case, still far from optimal) is not the same thing as explaining what the OP did wrong. Doesn't answer the OP's question, "why is my \[example\] working so slow?"

Answer (score 2):

"Finding prime numbers" is a *compute-bound* operation.  It will naturally use 100% CPU utilization because it never needs to perform I/O.

The two purposes of "multithreading" are: *(a)* to take advantage of multiple CPU cores, and *(b)* to overlap computation with I/O. (And to more-easily issue parallel I/O operations.)

Multithreading can save time in the right situation, *or* cost considerably more time in the wrong ones.

Your very ill-considered design appears to launch 20,000 threads!

Comment: This "answer" hints at the problem ("Your very ill-considered design...") but it does not actually _answer_ the OP's question.